# Trouble with my BMI program C#?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with my bmi calculator. 
Here are the details:

**Write a program that takes a person's height and
weight in pounds and returns the body mass index(BMI).
BMI is defined as the weight, expressed in kilograms,** **divided by the square of the height expressed in meters.**
**One inch is 0.0254 meters and one pound is
0.454 kilograms.**

This is a windows form app btw.

Well when I am trying to square the height using ^, it gives me an error: Operator '^'...

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare variables.
    decimal heightDecimal ;
    decimal weightDecimal;
    decimal bmiDecimal;
    decimal resultDecimal;

    //Get user input.
    heightDecimal = Decimal.Parse(txtHeight.Text);
    weightDecimal = Decimal.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

    //Calculations.
    weightDecimal = (Decimal)0.454;
    heightDecimal = (Decimal)0.0254;
    bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / heightDecimal ^ 2;




    //Display.
    lblBMI.Text = bmiDecimal.ToString();
}
```

I am trying to figure out the calculations. I am confused. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

**Tested what everyone said. I got some weird numbers. I started it and I put 5 for my height and 100 for my weight(random) and I got 700? Are my calculations wrong?**

Comment: Don't you know how to debug? Ask 2 question about a simple problem in only a few minutes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286759/how-to-calculate-for-bmi-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it would look like in a Console App:

```
        decimal feetDecimal;
        decimal inchesDecimal;
        decimal weightDecimal;
        decimal bmiDecimal;
        decimal resultDecimal;


        //Get user input.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter feet:");
        feetDecimal = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter inches:");
        inchesDecimal = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter weight in pounds:");
        weightDecimal = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Calculations. 
        inchesDecimal += feetDecimal * 12;
        decimal height = inchesDecimal * (decimal)0.0254;
        decimal weight = weightDecimal * (decimal)0.453592;
        bmiDecimal = weight / (height * height);
        //Display.
        Console.WriteLine(bmiDecimal.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks I actually got it to work. Even though mine wasn't console, I figured out based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / heightDecimal ^ 2;
```

You probably meant

```
bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / (heightDecimal  * heightDecimal);
```

^ is the [XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) in C#.

Edit:
If you don't use metric unit, you have to multiply the results by 703.06957964, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index).

Comment: But do my calculations look right? I just tested it, I enter 5 for my height and 100 for my weight and i got 700. That is way too high.

Comment: height 5? That means either 5 meters which makes you a giant or 5 inches so you fit in my backpack! (check your units)

Comment: I don't think I added units as me being a noobie. The code I put up on my post is what I am using. **I am making to where the user inputs their weight in lbs and it calculates it to kgs. I am using metric** Any help on how to do this.

Comment: This is a reply to @BrokenGlass

Comment: @GunnarBates Shouldn't `weightDecimal = (Decimal)0.454;` be `weightDecimal = weightDecimal * 0.454;`? (or `weightDecimal *= 0.454` for short)

Answer (score 1):

```
bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / (heightDecimal * heightDecimal);
```

Try the above. `^` is xor

Alternatively

```
bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / Math.Pow(heightDecimal, 2)
```

Some test values could be 90 kg and 1.80 m

```
90 / (1.80 * 1.80)
```

90 kg is roughly 200 lbs and 1.80 m is 5.11 if you're not used to the metric system

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework also provides a `Math` class that has a `Pow` method, which allows for squaring of numbers like this:

```
Math.Pow(2, 2)
```

That is 2 squared, which equals 4.

Your code would be:

```
bmiDecimal = weightDecimal / Math.Pow(heightDecimal, 2);
```

Note: For more information read [documentation for Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(txtWeight.Text);
                Height = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHeight.Text);

```
            BodyMassIndex = (Weight * 703) / (Height * Height);

            txtMassIndex.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(BodyMassIndex, 4) + " lbs/ Inch Square");
```